# Uploading a file from React to Express with axios.post isn't working

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I feel that I'm missing something tiny, for some reason this just isn't working. I'm trying to do an axios.post from React. I want to pass multiple values, including a pdf file. Console.log confirms that the full file is being sent from the React side. But when it gets to the Express side, only the file.path has been received and not the whole file.

React side:

```
    var file = newFileList[i];
    var content = newCreateList[i]
    axios
        .post(`/upload`, {file, content})
        .then(response => {
            // response stuff
    })
```

*if I do a console log on newFileList[i], it displays as a File object like it is supposed to*

Express side:

```
    const upload = async (body) => {
    try {
        console.log("BODY: ", body);
```

console.log displays:`

```
    BODY:  {
        file: { path: 'testFile.pdf' },
        content: {
            id: 0,
            name: 'name',
            language: 'language',
        }
    }
```

So, the file is no longer a File object, now it's just the file path.

I have also tried this on the React side instead, as it seems that this is what is recommended:

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', newFileList[i]);
    formData.append('info', newCreateList[i]);
    axios
        .post(`/upload`, formData)
        .then(response => {
            // response stuff
    })
```

*Then the console log on the Express side, just displays this:*

```
    BODY:  { info: '[object Object]' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a header configuration like this:

```
    axios
        .post(`/upload`, formData,{
          headers:{
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
       })
        .then(response => {
            // response stuff
    })
```

In the console younever will see the img or file just the metadata o the data in 64Base code